# Rails Convert YAML In Database To Array In Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, yaml

I have an array of integers that gets stored in my DB as yaml. I'm looking for a way to convert the yaml back to an array in my controller.

Here is the migration:

```
class AddRandomExerciseArrayToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, serialize :random_exercise_array, :text
  end
end
```

Here is what it looks like in the DB:

```
random_exercise_array: "---\n- 1\n- 2\n- 3\n- 5\n- 1\n- 0\n- 1\n- 2\n- 1\n- 4\n">
```

In the above instance how could I get an array of integers as follows [1,2,3,5,1,0,1,2,1,4] back into my controller?

**Edit:**

Relevant controller code:

```
def index   
    if current_user.bookmark2 == 0 && current_user.random_exercise_array.nil?
      exerciseArray = Array.new(10) 

      for i in 0..9
        exerciseArray[i] = rand(0..5)
      end

      current_user.random_exercise_array = exerciseArray
      current_user.save
    end 
end
```

Comment: Post on your model and controller scripts.

Comment: Updated with relevant controller code. Not sure what you mean by model script.

Comment: Your relevant model code is User class, can you post it on?

Comment: As I know, if you add `serialize  :random_exercise_array , Array` in your User model, you could use it as array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get useful information from this link(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html)

> If you have an attribute that needs to be saved to the database as an object, and retrieved as the same object, then specify the name of that attribute using this method and it will be handled automatically. The serialization is done through YAML.

```
class AddRandomExerciseArrayToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
      add_column :resources, :random_exercise_array, :text
  end
end
```

then run: rake db:migrate

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :random_exercise_array #add this line to your user model
end
```

If you store an array in DB, you can get an array directly and doesn't need to handle it by yourself.